# What is the proper/secure way to process payments in Flutter with Firebase Cloud Functions and Stripe?

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to build an e-commerce app where Sellers can post their items and sell it to buyers on my platform. The mobile app is built with Flutter and I am using Firebase Firestore and Storage to handle the data with Stripe as my payment processing choice.

I have come across this guide on Medium (https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-a-marketplace-in-your-flutter-app-and-accept-payments-using-stripe-and-firebase-72f3f7228625) that had done a great job in getting my feet wet into online payment processing.

However, one thing that he mentioned in there probably doesn't seem like a secure way to handle payment?

What he had done in the guide is that inside the client-app he made an https POST request

```
    final http.Response response = await http.post(‘$urlamount=$amount&currency=GBP&paym=${paymentMethod.id}’);
```

Then inside the cloud functions he went with:

```
exports.StripePI = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
const stripeVendorAccount = 'acct_someAccountIdHere';
stripe.paymentMethods.create(
   {
     payment_method: req.query.paym,
   }, {
     stripeAccount: stripeVendorAccount
   },
   function(err, clonedPaymentMethod){
      if(err != null) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          stripe.paymentIntents.create(
              {
                  **amount = req.query.amount**, // Security concern??
                  currency = req.query.currency,
                  ...etc
              }
          )
      }
   }
);
```

having to pass the total amount from the client-side seems to be not a good security practice? I can imagine maybe someone with enough knowledge can reverse engineer the app and edit that amount variable?

***So what is the proper way to set the amount?***

I have seen and read all the official guides from Google's firebase team's videos and posts however, when it comes to the amount it's just:

```
const amount = snap.data().amount;
```

I have thought about using Cloud functions to somehow add/sum up all the items' prices and quantities together to generate the amount however, is it really the most efficient way to approach this problem? If there are N many sellers with M ordered items from the buyers, wouldnt it cause a lot of unnecessary calculations from Cloud Functions?

I am new to mobile and online payments so thank you first for your patience.

Comment: Well, you still need to get this data from client somehow. Using an SSL or other encrypted connection should make it more secure.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of anything you're selling should be set on your server, preferably by getting it from a database.

Instead of sending an amount from your client, you should send a quantity instead.

Say you're selling T-shirts at $10 each and a user wants to buy 2. Instead of sending `amount=20` to your server, send `quantity=2` instead. Then on your server you should look up how much a single T-shirt costs and multiply that by the quantity (after making sure that quantity is larger than zero).

Setting an amount rather than quantity means a malicious user could reverse engineer your endpoint and instruct your server that they'd for instance like to buy 100 T-shirts for $0.

I wouldn't worry too much in terms of unnecessary calculations, as it all drills down to retrieving the item unit cost and multiplying that by a quantify.